# The derivative of one parameter group and Lie Bracket

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a complete vector field on a differentiable manifold $M$. Let $X_t$ be the global $1$-parameter transformation group. Fixing $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have a diffeomorphism $X_t: M\rightarrow M$ and its derivative $dX_t(p):T_pM\rightarrow T_{X_t(p)}M$.

Let $v$ be a vector field such that $dX_t(p)(v(p))=v(X_t(p))$ for all point $p$ of the manifold. Is it true that $[X,v]=0$?

Comment: You haven't given us coordinates on $M$, and unless you tell us what coordinates you'd like, the answer is $dX_t(p)$ can be any invertible matrix.

Comment: I thought of some general formula involving Lie bracket, but the question does need some context...

Comment: The answer to your updated question is yes. Your condition on $v$ is that $(X_t)_* v = v$, which I assume you want to hold for all $t$. So using that $[X,v] = \mathcal{L}_X v$ and the definition of the Lie derivative as $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{v - (X_{-t})_* v}{t} $ you have that the bracket vanishes.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an argument not involving the Lie derivative? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Well, you can always _prove_ as part of your argument that $[X,v] = \lim_{t \to 0} \ldots $ if you don't want to use the word Lie derivative. // You could certainly just work in a small neighborhood of $p$ and look at $t \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and do everything in coordinates, and you can get the desired result without mentioning Lie derivatives and just by doing coordinate computations. // What do you hope to gain by not thinking about Lie derivatives?

Comment: Ah so I’m asking for a proof that $[X,v]=L_X(v)$.